# How to apply a github action across multiple projects in my organization?

Tags: github, github-actions

In my company we have a few hundred repositories, for at least 20 of those we want to apply linting by doing github actions.
It seems not good to copy the same github action workflow into each `.github/workflows` folder for a few reasons one is that the action is duplicated, no single source of truth, there should be one file somewhere if we change it then all the other files change.

How to apply one github action to multiple github repositories without copying this file into every single `.github/workflows` folder in every one of these github projects?
This is a github enterprise account.

Comment: Did you check the official documentation about [Sharing actions and workflows with your enterprise](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-enterprise)? You will basically need to [allowing access to components in an internal repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-an-internal-repository).

Comment: @GuiFalourd tried it between two private repos in my org and didn't work

Comment: Does your company use an enterprise account, or is it a free tier account? One option could be to check the level of access of the workflows outside of the repository, using the Github API. [This service](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/actions/permissions#get-the-level-of-access-for-workflows-outside-of-the-repository) allows you to get this information, and [this other service](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/actions/permissions#set-the-level-of-access-for-workflows-outside-of-the-repository) to set the level of access.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this new feature (Jan. 2023) can help:

> ### [GitHub Actions – Support for organization-wide required workflows public beta](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-10-github-actions-support-for-organization-wide-required-workflows-public-beta) (Jan. 2023)
>
> Today, we are announcing public beta of required workflows in GitHub Actions
>
> Required workflows allow DevOps teams to define and enforce standard CI/CD practices across many source code repositories within an organization without needing to configure each repository individually.
> Organization admins can configure required workflows to run on all or selected repositories within the organization.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/25578249/211551996-c32d315d-e9a5-47fd-b74b-7263773ce77a.png?ssl=1 -- Required workflows at the organization level]
>
> Required workflows will be triggered as required status checks for all the pull requests opened on the default branch, which blocks the ability to merge the pull request until the required workflow succeeds.
>
> Individual development teams at the repository level will be able to see what required workflows have been applied to their repository.
>
> https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/25578249/211552010-d7aa7c25-f204-4c20-a04b-9c53f74ec52e.png?ssl=1 -- Required workflows run at repo
>
> In addition to reducing duplication of CI/CD configuration code, required workflows can also help companies with the following use cases:
>
> - Security: Invoke external vulnerability scoring or dynamic analysis tools.
> - Compliance: Ensure that all code meets an enterprise’s quality standards.
> - Deployment: Ensure that code is continuously deployed in a standard way.
>
> [Learn more about required workflows](https://docs.github.com//en/actions/using-workflows/required-workflows)